# iOS - Best practices for FileManager extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, extension-methods, nsfilemanager

I created this `FileManager` `extension`. With this `extension`, I want to create a file hierarchy like so:

> - Application Support
>
>   - Favorites
>   - Feed
>
>     - Images

This is the code I have in `FileManager` `extension` which I would call in `app delegate` as soon as the app launches. Then I would use this code to always retrieve the `path`'s of the folders.

Is this a good way to create this hierarchy and retrieve the paths when I need them? Is this good practice?

```
extension FileManager {
    static func createOrFindApplicationDirectory() -> URL? {
        let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
        // Find the application support directory in the home directory.
        let appSupportDir = self.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

        guard appSupportDir.count > 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        // Append the bundle ID to the URL for the Application Support directory.
        let dirPath = appSupportDir[0].appendingPathComponent(bundleID!)

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating Application Support directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func createOrFindFavoritesDirectory() -> URL? {
        guard let appSupportDir = createOrFindApplicationDirectory() else {
            return nil
        }

        let dirPath = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent("Favorites")

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating Favorites directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func createOrFindFeedDirectory() -> URL? {
        guard let appSupportDir = createOrFindFavoritesDirectory() else {
            return nil
        }

        let dirPath = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent("Feed")

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating Favorites directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func currentImagesDirectory() -> URL? {
        guard let feedDir = createOrFindFeedDirectory() else {
            return nil
        }

        let dirPath = feedDir.appendingPathComponent("Images")

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating Images directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @ILikeTau Thanks! Is there anything you would do different? I would love to see some other examples, wether your own code or a tutorial/link that has something similar to what I am trying to do.

Comment: I might combine `createOrFindFavoritesDirectory()` and `createOrFindFeedDirectory()` into one function that takes an argument, but other than that all of it looks fine.

Comment: @ILikeTau Could you post an answer with that? I'm just curious to see how others would do this - trying to learn from others who are better than me : )

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good, but you could combine a bit of the code and have better error checking:

```
extension FileManager {
    static func createOrFindApplicationDirectory() -> URL? {
        guard let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else {
            return nil
        }

        // Find the application support directory in the home directory.
        let appSupportDirArray = self.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

        guard let appSupportDir = appSupportDirArray.first else {
            return nil
        }

        // Append the bundle ID to the URL for the Application Support directory.
        let dirPath = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent(bundleID)

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating Application Support directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func createOrFindDirectory(named name: String) -> URL? {
        guard let appSupportDir = createOrFindApplicationDirectory() else {
            return nil
        }

        let dirPath = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent(name)

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating \(name) directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func currentImagesDirectory() -> URL? {
        guard let feedDir = createOrFindDirectory(named: "Feed") else {
            return nil
        }

        let dirPath = feedDir.appendingPathComponent("Images")

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        do {
            try self.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            return dirPath
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating Images directory with error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice! I see that you combined the Feed and Favorite into one function `static func createOrFindDirectory(named name: String) -> URL?`, cool. In terms of 'error checking', I really need these folders/directories to be created when the app is first launched. How do you handle an error besides returning `nil` so that I guarantee these folders are created before progressing? Point is, without these folders created at app launch, my app would not work correctly

Comment: Since you mentioned error handling, it got me thinking more.. I'm not sure exactly when "creating" one of these folders could fail, but in case it does, not sure how to handle it so that app won't progress until they are created